# create a .war file from gwt-project

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, war

How do I create a .war-file from my gwt-project in eclipse?

Comment: http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-make-war-file-in-eclipse.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I always use Ant build file, so the project gets compiled and packaged as a war with one click.

Add an xml-file to your project with the following content:

```
<project name="test" basedir="." default="default">
<property name="src.dir" value="src" />
<property name="build.dir" value="war" />
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${build.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
        <include name="**/*.xml" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="default" depends="gwtc, buildwar,deploy">
</target>

<target name="gwtc" description="GWT compile to JavaScript">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${src.dir}" />
            <path refid="compile.classpath" />
        </classpath>
        <arg line="-logLevel INFO" />
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx1024M" />
        <arg value="YourProject.EntryPointClass" />
    </java>
</target>

<target name="buildwar">
    <war basedir="war" destfile="YourProject.war" webxml="war/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <exclude name="WEB-INF/**" />
        <webinf dir="war/WEB-INF/">
            <include name="**/gwt-servlet.jar" />
            <include name="**/classes/**" />
        </webinf>
    </war>
</target>

<target name="deploy">
    <copy file="YourProject.war" todir="." />
</target>

</project>
```

(Edit `YourProject.EntryPointClass to the path to your EntryPoint-class)

You would need to add `gwt-user.jar` and `gwt-dev.jar`to your projects build path(right click on your project -> Build Path -> Add External Achives).

If you now look at your "Problems"-view you get a warning that the two files are not available on the server's class path. You can use the QuickFix to either copy it to `WEB-INF/lib` or hide the warning. The build file will not include those two file in the war-file.

All you need to do to compile and create the file is to right click the xml-file and select run as Ant Build.

Comment: The xml file is not ended correctly, please fix it for completeness.

Comment: Should the direction wording in this answer, "the path to your EntryPoint-class", instead be "the path to your module file (<YourProject>.gwt.xml)"?

In my case (from the official GWT tutorial: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/create.html), that ended up being "com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.StockWatcher", where com was the first dir under src, and StockWatcher is the name of the .gwt.xml module file at the end of that path (using that made a successful compile & .war).  Instead before that entering the path to the Java .class file of the EntryPoint-class did not work.

Comment: Just pointing these [maybe obvious things] out for those who are helped by seeing it explicitly here...  I'm not sure if it was absolutely necessary, but I also changed "<project name="test"" to "<project name="<MyProjectName>"".  I also changed "destfile="YourProject.war"" to "destfile="MyProjectName.war"" (I assume that one isn't absolutely necessary, but sensible).

Comment: FYI:  The .war will be placed at the root of your Eclipse project path.  That was the same level as where I put this build.xml, but not visible from Eclipse (only from my file system explorer).

Comment: I think "You would need to add gwt-user.jar and gwt-dev.jarto your projects build path" is the same as adding GWT SDK to the project build path (as the SDK contains those jars)?  I'm not sure, because I had the SDK, but I still had to manually add those jars to WEB-INF/lib to prevent "Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler"

Comment: FYI:  Ant seems to not like space chars in paths on Windows.  So I had to move my eclipse from C:/.../Program Files to C:/

Comment: I think "(Edit `YourProject.EntryPointClass to the path to your EntryPoint-class)" should be "(Edit `YourProject.EntryPointClass to the path to your .gwt.xml module file)".

Answer (score 12):

Using Eclipse:

1. right click the project
2. choose Google→GWT Compile
3. when compilation has finished, the console will say i.e.

   > Linking into /home/janus/bpworkspace/gwtwerkstatt2/war/gwtwerkstatt2
   >
   > Link succeeded
   >
   > Compilation succeeded -- 28.623s
4. open a terminal and navigate to the directory
5. create the WAR: `jar cv * > /tmp/myGWTproject.war`
6. you can now launch it with jetty-runner or similar: `java -jar jetty-runner-8.1.7.v20120910.jar /tmp/myGWTproject.war`

Comment: Note to anybody stumbling across this answer like I just did: you have to do "jar cvf YourWar.war ." from the war directory, not the directory that's linked into during step 3.

Comment: If you project has any project dependencies, you may also have to compile them and put the .jar files into the war/WEB-INF/lib folder before creating the .war file. You have to repeat this anytime they're updated.

Answer (score 4):

I just found this solution, and it's amazing :)
Just install the jar and enjoy extracting to a war file.

Project Site
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-project-export-wizard/

Answer (score 2):

One can also use **webAppCreator** to generate Ant build file.

webAppCreator ships with GWT SDK and also with Eclipse GWT Plugin. First locate GWT plugin directory

```
find $HOME/.eclipse/ -name "*gwt*sdk*"
```

this will output GWT plugin dir path. This dir has gwt dir something like gwt-2.4.0. WebAppCreator will be in this dir. Set this dir as GWTSDK_HOME.

```
export GWTSDK_HOME=/home/m/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_1364963873/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201201120043-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0
```

make webAppCreator executable

```
chmod 755 $GWTSDK_HOME/webAppCreator
```

Now create a project using webAppCreator in some temp dir.

```
$GWTSDK_HOME/webAppCreator -out fins in.m.fins.Fins
```

**in.m.fins.Fins** is the module name. This has to match with your project's gwt.xml in Eclipse workspace. If your gwt.xml is  **src/in/m/fins/Fins.gwt.xml** then module name should be **in.m.fins.Fins**

**-out fins** will create the project and build.xml in fins directory. Copy generated build.xml file to your project in Eclipse workspace.

Run war target in Eclipse Ant Window to package your project as war

Answer (score 1):

You have to have GWT designer installed from here

> http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/3.7

1. In Eclipse on the main panel click on "Deploy module on aplication server" (It's next to blue google button).
2. Chose war file name and location where to store it
3. Click ok

That's it. Works on my GWT 2.4.0, Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2, Eclipse Juno

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: you'll find another tutorial on how to create a .war using Eclipse on [http://blog.elitecoderz.net/](http://blog.elitecoderz.net/en/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12/).

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Fist compile your project. Then:
1. Open your project.
2. Navigate to war folder.
3. Go to File>Export>Archive File
4. Export your war FOLDER as zip file.
5. Change your file extension form .zip to .war
6. Keep calm and enjoy your war file.

Answer (score -1):

Compile your project. Then:

1. Open your project.
2. Navigate to war folder.
3. Go to File>Export>Archive File
4. Export your war FOLDER as zip file.
5. Change your file extension form .zip to .war
6. Keep calm and enjoy your war file.

Comment: I don't think that this is what the Op asked for even though the question might suggest it.