# Issue while executing buildscript for generating war for GWTP project

Tags: java, gwt, ant, build.xml, gwt-platform

I am getting an error while trying to run a build for generating a war file for my gwtp application. The error is as follows:

```
> gwtc:
         [java] Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.user.User'
         [java]    Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.core.Core'
         [java]       Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.core.CompilerParameters'
         [java]          [WARN] Setting configuration property named compiler.max.vars.per.var in com.google.gwt.core.CompilerParameters that has not been previously defined.  This may be disallowed in the future.
         [java] Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.resources.Resources'
         [java]    [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/google/gwt/resources/Resources.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
         [java] [ERROR] Line 6: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
         [java] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:239)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:354)
         [java]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
         [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
         [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:223)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:270)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1342)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2770)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:327)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:398)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:257)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:169)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:283)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:141)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:184)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:152)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:159)
         [java] [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
         [java] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.DefaultSchema.onHandlerException(DefaultSchema.java:56)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:66)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:66)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:233)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:270)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1342)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2770)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
         [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:327)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:398)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:257)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:169)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:283)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:141)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:184)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:152)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:159)
         [java] [ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
         [java] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:351)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:398)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:257)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:169)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:283)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:141)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:184)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:152)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
         [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:159)


BUILD FAILED
...\build.xml:16: Java returned: 1

Total time: 1 second
```

The build.xml is as follows and is taken from the post ([create a .war file from gwt-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403099/create-a-war-file-from-gwt-project/5404145#5404145)) :

```
 <project name="MyProject" basedir="." default="default">
    <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
    <property name="build.dir" value="war" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="${build.dir}/WEB-INF/lib" />
    <path id="compile.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${build.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
            <include name="**/*.xml" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="default" depends="gwtc, buildwar,deploy">
    </target>

    <target name="gwtc" description="GWT compile to JavaScript">
        <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${src.dir}" />
                <pathelement location="${lib.dir}" />
                <path refid="compile.classpath" />
            </classpath>
            <arg line="-logLevel INFO" />
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx1024M" />
            <arg value="org.company.prj.MyProject" />
        </java>
    </target>

    <target name="buildwar">
        <war basedir="war" destfile="MyProject.war" webxml="war/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <exclude name="WEB-INF/**" />
            <webinf dir="war/WEB-INF/">
                <include name="**/gwt-servlet.jar" />
                <include name="**/classes/**" />
            </webinf>
        </war>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy">
        <copy file="MyProject.war" todir="." />
    </target>

    </project>
```

Comment: Could you restyle your question so that the exception looks like the code block does the actual text you type is not within the code block? It will make it a little easier to read.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that now.

Comment: It looks like the compile is starting correctly, but just dying on the Resources inherits, so you may want to check that your client bundle is set up correctly. Are you using eclipse for development? If so does it compile all the way through in there?

Comment: its compiles in eclpise, but the build.xml fails.