# What is the standard way of generating WAR file for a GWT project?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, gwt, war

What is the standard way of generating war file for a GWT project?

I am implementing a simple GWT project with Eclipse Mars. I am using GWT SDK 2.7.0 and Tomcat 7.0.67.

My current way of creating war file is that after 'Google -> GWT Compile' the project, cd to {wordspace}\myproject\war folder and then enter command 'jar -cvf myproject.war *'.

What's very strange is that from time to time, the UI result displayed on http://localhost:8080/myproject/ is far different from expected. It's even different from **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\myproject\entrypoint.html** as I manually checked it. In contrast, the result of 'Run As -> Web Application (GWT Super Dev Mode)' is always OK and always identical to what I expect.

I have also tried other .war creation methods like 'Export -> Web -> WAR File' in Eclipse and the one on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_deploy_application.htm. The former always doesn't work, and the latter does not work better than 'jar -cvf myproject.war *'.

The questions are:

1. What's a more standard, more reliable way of WAR file creation for a GWT project, so that after copying and pasting a newly created war file to **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps**), the result on http://localhost:8080/myproject/ can be always fine, or always identical to that on http://127.0.0.1:8888/myproject.html after running this GWT project on Eclipse 'as Web Application (GWT Super Dev Mode)'? (the major question)
2. Are there any configuration mistakes I'm unaware of which make this (the web page results on GWT Super Dev Mode and on http://localhost:8080/myproject/ after deploying war file are incongruent) happen?

Comment: There's a fairly basic Ant build script that'll assemble the .war file for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5404145/1740724

Comment: A "standard way" would be to rely on a build tool that can automate the tasks (and preferably guarantees a stable outcome given the outputs), rather than an IDE.

Comment: I use gradle for my builds.