# Deploy gwt app online

Tags: maven, gwt, deployment, ant, war

I am trying to deploy online my GWT Application. As I understood from the GWT website, a good way to do it is by deploying the .war file.

My problem is the following: I cannot obtain a .war file, and I dont succeed in deploying it in another way.

I already took a look on the subject about obtaining war file from GWT ([create a .war file from gwt-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403099/create-a-war-file-from-gwt-project)) and none of the solutions worked.

When I run my app locally (from Eclipse), it works well. 
Does anybody has an idea about how to deploy it ?

I need your help :(

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

To generate WAR file from GWT project application use this:

With maven: use org.codehaus.mojo and package project as war. `<packaging>war</packaging>`

With no maven and only Eclipse IDE:

- Go to Properties project - > Project Facets: enable 'dynamic web    project'
- Apply changes
- right click on project and select export->web->war file and put the web project and destination to save.

Thats all, you have a war file

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any server-side Java code? If not, then war is a rather bad export format. For just using the GWT frontend, stick to compiling the project and using the generated directory (the one that will contain the html, a .nocache.js and a directory with your GWT module).